# guard file not detecting change in haml view files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, guard

My guard default config is as follows

```
guard :rspec, cmd: "bundle exec rspec" do
  require "guard/rspec/dsl"
  dsl = Guard::RSpec::Dsl.new(self)

  # Feel free to open issues for suggestions and improvements

  # RSpec files
  rspec = dsl.rspec
  watch(rspec.spec_helper) { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rspec.spec_support) { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rspec.spec_files)

  # Ruby files
  ruby = dsl.ruby
  dsl.watch_spec_files_for(ruby.lib_files)

  # Rails files
  rails = dsl.rails(view_extensions: %w(erb haml slim))
  dsl.watch_spec_files_for(rails.app_files)
  dsl.watch_spec_files_for(rails.views)

  watch(rails.controllers) do |m|
    [
      rspec.spec.call("routing/#{m[1]}_routing"),
      rspec.spec.call("controllers/#{m[1]}_controller"),
      rspec.spec.call("acceptance/#{m[1]}")
    ]
  end

  # Rails config changes
  watch(rails.spec_helper)     { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rails.routes)          { "#{rspec.spec_dir}/routing" }
  watch(rails.app_controller)  { "#{rspec.spec_dir}/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(rails.view_dirs)     { |m| rspec.spec.call("features/#{m[1]}") }
  watch(rails.layouts)       { |m| rspec.spec.call("features/#{m[1]}") }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) do |m|
    Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || "spec/acceptance"
  end
end
```

When i change a haml file guard doesnt detect and run tests. I am using rspecs with guard. Does anything need to be added to the default guardfile in order to detect haml changes? Thanks for the help!